# jQuery progress bar not saving after 2 file uploads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page with numerous rows of input fields and each row has a file upload button. Ever since integrating the code below to display a progress bar, I can upload 1 file and once it has uploaded it saved automatically as intended. When I upload a second file it does the same thing. When I upload a third file, the photo uploads but the row does not automatically save and will only work again once the page is refreshed. This is slowing me down and the only thing I've changed is the addition of the below code. Is there something wrong with how it is written?

Upload code:

```
function bindFileUpload() {
    var inventoryPasscode = '<?=$inventory_passcode?>';
    $('.fileupload').fileupload({
        formData: {passcode: inventoryPasscode},
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                data.form.find('.itemPhotoFile').val(file.name);
            });
        postFormItems($(this).closest('form.item').get(0));
        }
    });
};

// End upload function
```

The progress bar code (the change):

```
//PROGRESS
    $('.fileupload').fileupload({
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        $('.bar').fadeIn();
    },
        stop: function(){
            $('.bar').fadeOut();
        }
    });
//PROGRESS END
```

Comment: Does the third file upload at all? or is it just the 3rd progress bar that is not working properly? what does your html structure look like?

Comment: The progress bar displays and the file uploads then the bar disappears as required - but the row does not save automatically (it will flash green)

Comment: When you say row, do you mean a row in the database or a row in the table showing the uploads?

Comment: A row in the database which consists of item, description, condition, photo - all are input fields with a save button. Once a photo is uploaded, the row is automatically saved to send the file name to the database, but if it does not save automatically it doesn't get sent even if you press the save button

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net